How to Only See Specific Column Values based on Related Columns
I'm working on a Power BI Report that uses data in a SharePoint list. Basically what I want to do is only show the value from the Hazard columns, if the corresponding level is Medium or High (Hazard 1 level is Level 1, hazard 2 is level 2, etc.).

I've messed around with combining the columns and different visuals but really am unsure of how to get after what I'm trying to do. The attached image is a scaled down version of the dataset.

Can you please provide an example of the expected output?

what's the expected output based on the sample data you provided?

I created 3 calculated columns:
Conditional Hazard 1 = IF('Table'[Level 1] in {"Medium", "High"}, 'Table'[Hazard 1], BLANK()) 

Conditional Hazard 2 = IF('Table'[Level 2] in {"Medium", "High"}, 'Table'[Hazard 2], BLANK()) 

Conditional Hazard 3 = IF('Table'[Level 3] in {"Medium", "High"}, 'Table'[Hazard 3], BLANK()) 

Example Output:

